# How to plot the differential equation in spherical coordinates with maple

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, maple

I want to plot the position of Spherical pendulum.
there are differential equation for [spherical pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_pendulum) in [Spherical Coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html).

```
sys := {((D@@2)(phi))(t) = -2*(D(phi))(t)*(D(theta))(t)*cos(theta(t))/sin(phi(t)), 
((D@@2)(theta))(t) = (D(phi))(t)^2*cos(theta(t))*sin(theta(t))-9.8*sin(theta(t))}
```

$$\theta ''(t)=\sin (\theta (t))\cos (\theta (t)) \phi '(t)^2- 9.8\sin (\theta (t))
$$

$$\phi''(t)=\frac{-2 \phi'(t)\theta'(t)\cos(\theta(t))}{\sin(\theta(t))}$$

with initial conditions

```
 theta(0) = (1/2)*Pi, (D(theta))(0) = 0, phi(0) = (1/2)*Pi, (D(phi))(0) = 1
```

I tried:

```
eq := dsolve([((D@@2)(theta))(t) = (D(phi))(t)^2*cos(theta(t))-9.8*sin(theta(t)), 
((D@@2)(phi))(t) = -2*(D(phi))(t)*(D(theta))(t)*cos(theta(t))/sin(phi(t)), 
theta(0) = (1/2)*Pi, (D(theta))(0) = 0, phi(0) = (1/2)*Pi, (D(phi))(0) = 1],numeric)
```

how to change coordinates

```
x(t) = sin(theta(t))*cos(phi(t))
y(t) = sin(theta(t))*sin(phi(t))
z(t) = cos(theta(t))
```

and how to plot it from t=0 to 10?

Comment: Can you write out the equations instead of putting them in Maple format?

Comment: @Moo ok, I edit my question

Comment: One of the terms in your  Maple code for `sys` has `sin(phi(t))` in the denominator, but your corresponding inlined formula has it as `sin(theta(t))` instead (as pointed out by Preben Alsholm on www.mapleprimes.com).

Answer (score 0):

Whether using spherical or cylindrical, plotting of results are in Cartesian system of co-ordinates.

After solving and finding spherical  $ (\theta , \phi) $ just plug in, find out $ (x,y,z)$ and plot the locus points.

Comment: can you write down maple code. (maple format)?

Comment: I see no error, Why not ask on Maple site ?